# Linux daemon waiting for a socket connection

Tags: bash, sockets, daemon

I would like to create a simple Linux daemon which will...

- open a tcp/ip server socket on localhost and specified port
- wait for a connection
- after someone connects, it will read the first line from the client's socket (ended by `\n`)
- if the line is `foo`, it will run command `bar`
- after the `bar` command is finished (or if the line wasn't `foo`), the daemon will wait for another connection and do the same (in infinite loop)...

Is it possible to write this in bash? (And how?)

Also, I would like to be able to start and stop the script with `service my-foobar-daemon start / stop` (on Ubuntu), how can I do that?

Thanks :)

Comment: `inetd` will do most of that for you, there are various flavours to investigate for your specific requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet uses `bash` and `nc` to implement the requirements:

```
#! /bin/bash
while true; do
    coproc nc -l -p 8080
    if read -u "${COPROC[0]}" line; then
        case "$line" in
            foo)
                bar
                ;;
            *)
                echo "$line: unknown command" >&2
                ;;
        esac
    fi
    kill "$COPROC_PID"
    wait "$COPROC_PID"
done
```

Comment: I used `coproc` to close the connection after the first line. If the client shuts down the connection after one line, the script will be a lot simpler - and `coproc` is not required.

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /bin/bash
coproc nc -l -p 8080
while true; do
    if read -u "${COPROC[0]}" line; then
        case "$line" in
            foo)
                bar
                break
                ;;
            *)
                echo "$line: unknown command" >&2
                ;;
        esac
    fi
done
kill "$COPROC_PID"
```